# Criar Web Service reaproveitando código de um site já publicado. Boas práticas em Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, web-service

Preciso criar um `web service` em `JSON` reaproveitando o máximo de código que meu site possuí, porém não sei como fazer, se devo adicionar uma solution no meu projeto do site etc. Não consigo abstrair a idéia, preciso depois disso acessar ele de uma aplicação Windows Phone que também é C#. Preciso que postem exemplos e boas práticas, de preferência usando a biblioteca NewtonSoft.

Comment: Você diz, Web API?

Comment: Preciso de um webservice, se Web API é a mesma coisa que isso então vale hehe, preciso que seja em JSON não xml.

Comment: Então é Web API ou REST API. Vou colocar um roteiro pra você.

Comment: Ok, estou no aguardo e valeu desde já!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Roteiro de como habilitar sua aplicação ASP.NET MVC5 para Web API

Há vários tutoriais pela internet, mas resolvi fazer algo bem sucinto como resposta. O resto fica como fonte de consulta.

### 1. Global.asax.cs

Abra seu `Global.asax.cs` e modifique ele de forma a ter a linha apontada abaixo:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        // Acrescente a linha abaixo.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        // Comente a linha abaixo se ela existir.
        // WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
}
```

### 2. /App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs

Crie o arquivo `WebApiConfig.cs` se ele não existir. Verifique se ele possui o seguinte conteúdo:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        // Essas linhas abaixo não são obrigatórias, mas elas garantem
        // que sempre vou devolver JSON.
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
}
```

### 3. Crie um Controller

Nos meus projetos, normalmente eu defino um diretório chamado `APIControllers` pra separar o que é `Controller` do site MVC e do Web API. Neste diretório do seu projeto, clique com o botão direito, escolha **Add** > **Controller**. A seguinte tela deve aparecer:

[image: Add Scaffold]

Escolha a opção **Web API 2 Controller with Actions, using Entity Framework**.

Dê um nome a ele na próxima tela e defina mais algumas coisas:

[image: Controller]

Defina o Model que será usado para gerar o `Controller` e o contexto de dados usado (tem a opção de gerar outro contexto, se for necessário). Clique em <kbd>Ok</kbd>.

Seu `Controller` será gerado com algo assim:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private MeuProjetoContext db = new MeuProjetoContext ();

    // GET api/Products
    public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return db.Products;
    }

    // GET api/Products/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProduct(Guid id)
    {
        Product product = await db.Products.FindAsync(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(product);
    }

    // PUT api/Products/5
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutProduct(Guid id, Product product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != product.ProductId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ProductExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST api/Products
    [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProduct(Product product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Products.Add(product);

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (ProductExists(product.ProductId))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = product.ProductId }, product);
    }

    // DELETE api/Products/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteProduct(Guid id)
    {
        Product product = await db.Products.FindAsync(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Products.Remove(product);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(product);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool ProductExists(Guid id)
    {
        return db.Products.Count(e => e.ProductId == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

Isto já é o suficiente para o seu sistema responder requisições pelo endereço:

> api/Products